# Registering implementation type is not assignable to service type on upgrade to .Net 6

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I am getting the following error with Azure Functions:

> A host error has occurred during startup operation {{Guid}} Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Host registering implementation type {{type}} is not assignable to service type {{interface}}.

Using `IFunctionHostBuilder` in `StartUp` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) with `builder.Services.AddSingleton<{{interface}}, {{type}}>();` for registering the type. I have updated Scrutor NuGet package to 4.2.0. Thought originally may relate to construction parameters in .NET Standard project maybe causing the problem, however, targeting .NET 6 for those projects still getting the same error. Has anyone had similar issues when upgrading to .Net 6 or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: No stack trace as no exception thrown just this in the console 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')'